# How to secure access to SWF file using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, flash, security, iis

We have a swf file that we want to secure and make available only to authorized users.

I embedded the file in an aspx page and that works fine, since ASP.NET handles the aspx page, I can use ASP.NET authorization features and in the web.config restrict the access to roles="AllowedUsers" for example.

However smart users could still get to the file by accessing directly for example www.mysite/flash.swf. We want to make that kind of access *secure*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aristos,

You were right. Last afternoon just before I went home I tried creating a custom HTTP handler. And it worked nice. :-) Thanks for answering +1

```
public class CustomFlashHandler : IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    context.Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2felVideo.aspx");
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    return;
  }

  var url = context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) return;

  HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("filename={0}", url));
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(url);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}

public bool IsReusable
{
  get { return false; }
}
```

}

Like Aristos said, you have to map ASP.NET to handle .swf files in IIS.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30424ac60a.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30424ac60a.png)

Then add the custom mapping in the application's web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.swf" type="XXXXX.Web.XXXXX.CustomFlashHandler" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

[1](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30424ac60a.png): href=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/>http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30424ac60a.png

[1](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30424ac60a.png): a href=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/>http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30424ac60a.png border=0 alt="Free Image Hosting">

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most easy and fast solution is to Map this extention (.swf) to handle by asp.net.

I do not know if its works, because I do not have done that, but you can give it a try.

**One other way** is to place this files, somewhere hidden, or with complex name, and use an **.ashx** file to just read and send them. In the .ashx file you need to set the correct **Response.ContentType** for the flash, and just read and send the **correct file**.